# is Object.prototype.toString.call() a security issue?

Tags: javascript, security, underscore.js, primitive

My doubt is: should I check for just primitive values (i.e using `Number.isFinite()` or `Number.isInteger()`) because "object" values are prone to security flaws?

If yes, methods like Underscore'`s _.isNumber()` (based on Object.toString) should be avoided?

Here is an example of malicious object that acts like a Number but can execute any code.

```
class Num extends Number {

    constructor (q) {
        super (q);
        this.value = q;
    }

    valueOf () {
        console.log('HACKED');
        return this.value;
    }
}

var n = new Num(5); // Num {5, value: 5}
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(n)); // [object Number]
console.log(Number.isFinite(n)); // false
var x = n + 1; // HACKED
console.log(x); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by, *malicious object that acts like a Number but can execute any code*

What you have done is simply Override the `valueOf` method of you custom Object `Num`.

From MDN,

> JavaScript calls the valueOf method to convert an object to a
>   primitive value

In your code `var x = n + 1;`, since n is of type Object and 1 is of primitive type, javascript tries to invoke `valueOf` to get the primitive value of n and add it to 1.

Since its your own object with your overidden `valueOf` method, your custom `valueOf` will be executed for converting the Object to primitive type.

Read more about [valueOf](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).

Comment: I obtain a value (n), I check the type because I'm expecting it's a number, I pass the test (Object.toString), then I do a simple sum, it works so I don't notice that the malicious code "console.log('HACKED')" is executed too.

Comment: valueOf got executed only because you tried to add a primitive number with an Object. It won't get executed otherwise. Also, popular libraries like Underscore.js are opensource and the code is available in GitHub. Hence you can check the code yourself for any suspicious lines and decide whether to use or not. Popular libraries like these won't be of any problem. But if it's a new/unknown library just be sure to verify it's source or if it's trustworthy.

Comment: so the answer to my question is "yes" ?